# Using lists to work with feature classes having different spatial references in ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system

This is my first arcpy script attempting to use lists.

**Input:** 4 dif Excel files, each with a dif spatial reference

**Output:** 4 dif feature classes (in same geodatabase), each with original spatial reference converted to NAD 1983.

**Issue:** I can make 4 dif (but similar) scripts and have Python work for each input BUT is there a way to have Python go through my **input** list? The problem is that for the second step,  `arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management`, I don't know how to rotate through the spatial references depending on which Excel file I am using. Trying to use user suggested idea of sub-lists.

*Updated Pasted script from Notepad:*

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set workspace
env.workspace = r"E:\GIS\1.gdb\\"

# Set the spatial reference
sr1 = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")
sr2 = arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1927")
sr3 = arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1983")


# Set variables
textPath1 = r"E:\GIS\Excel_files_by_datum\\"                                            
textPath2 = r"E:\GIS\2015Q1\\"
textPath3 = r"E:\GIS\1.gdb\\"
input = [["WGS84.xlsx", sr1],["NAD27.xlsx",sr2],["NAD83.xlsx",sr3],["Long_0_or_blank.xlsx",sr3]]
out_Layer = "XY_Temp"
Layername = input[0:5]

#Run processes

for ss in input:
    try:
        print "Converting Excel file to table"
        # Convert Excel to table
        Table1 = arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(textPath1+ ss[0],textPath3 + Layername)

        print "Making XY event layer"
        # This is to take the xy values of the table and transform to points
        # Description: Creates an XY layer and exports it to a layer file
        XY_event = arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Table1,"LONGITUDE","LATITUDE",out_Layer, ss[0])

        print "Copying features"
        # Description: Creates geodatabase feature class from the xy layer
        FeatureCopy = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(XY_event, Layername + "_temp")

        print "Making feature layer"
        # Description: Transforms xy event layer into feature layer so I can select from it
        FeatureLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FeatureCopy, Layername + "_temp2")

        print "Converting from original datum to NAD83"
        # Converts file from input datum to NAD83
        Transformed = arcpy.Project_management(FeatureLayer,textPath3 + Layername + "_to_NAD83",ss[2])

        print "Adding xy coordinates to feature layer table"
        # Adds new NAD83 xy coordinates to feature layer table
        arcpy.AddXY_management(Transformed)

        print "Deleting temp file"
        # Deletes temp FeatureCopy file
        arcpy.Delete_management(FeatureCopy)

        print "Deleting original table"
        # Deletes table from before the NAD 83 xy coordinates were added
        arcpy.Delete_management(Table1)

        print "Project complete"

    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: Modified **input** list to include NAD27 file

Comment: Updated code to include user suggested 'sub-list' idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, there's quite a bit wrong. I tried to do a quick cleanup, but admit I didn't test it:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
import os

# Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:\\GIS\\1.gdb"

# Set the spatial reference
sr1 = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")
sr2 = arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1927")
sr3 = arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1983")

# Set variables
textPath1 = "E:\\GIS\\Excel_files_by_datum"
textPath2 = "E:\\GIS\\2015Q1"
textPath3 = "E:\\GIS\\1.gdb"

input_data = [["WGS84.xlsx", sr1],["NAD27.xlsx", sr2],["NAD83.xlsx", sr3],["Long_0_or_blank.xlsx", sr3]]

#Run processes
for data in input_data:
    try:
        layer_name = data[0].split(".")[0]
        out_layer = str(layer_name) + "_XY_Temp"

        print "Converting Excel file to table"
        # Convert Excel to table
        Table1 = arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(os.path.join(textPath1, str(data[0])), os.path.join(textPath3, layer_name))

        print "Making XY event layer"
        # This is to take the xy values of the table and transform to points
        # Description: Creates an XY layer and exports it to a layer file
        XY_event = arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Table1, "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE", out_layer, data[1])

        print "Copying features"
        # Description: Creates geodatabase feature class from the xy layer
        FeatureCopy = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(XY_event, layer_name + "_temp")

        print "Making feature layer"
        # Description: Transforms xy event layer into feature layer so I can select from it
        FeatureLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FeatureCopy, layer_name + "_temp2")

        print "Converting from original datum to NAD83"
        # Converts file from input datum to NAD83
        Transformed = arcpy.Project_management(FeatureLayer, os.path.join(textPath3, layer_name + "_to_NAD83"), sr3)

        print "Adding xy coordinates to feature layer table"
        # Adds new NAD83 xy coordinates to feature layer table
        arcpy.AddXY_management(Transformed)

        print "Deleting temp file"
        # Deletes temp FeatureCopy file
        arcpy.Delete_management(FeatureCopy)

        print "Deleting original table"
        # Deletes table from before the NAD 83 xy coordinates were added
        arcpy.Delete_management(Table1)

        print "Project complete"

    except:
        arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: Thank you! It gave me properly named outputs! But I must have done something wrong because when I went to add the feature classes to the map they were all in their original spatial references. Was **arcpy.Project_management** the wrong tool to use to transform to NAD83?

Comment: @WolverineTime yeah, sorry. I had deleted my answer because I don't like posting untested code. I've updated the code to project to NAD83. I had misread at first.

Comment: thank you so much!!! It worked perfectly. I will have to study your code so I can get this right myself next time. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I think The best way would be to embed your spatial references into your list as sub-lists, i.e.:

```
input = [["WGS84.xlsx",sr1],["NAD83.xlsx",sr2],["WGS84.xlsx",sr3],["Long_0_or_blank.xlsx",sr1]]
```

Then update your script to (note use of ss[]):

```
for ss in input:
    try:
        # ...
        Table1 = arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(textPath1 + ss[0], textPath3 + Layername)
        # ...
        Transformed = arcpy.Project_management(FeatureLayer, textPath3 + Layername + "_to_NAD83", ss[1])
```

Comment: Thank you @slibby! I'm trying that now. I received an _invalid syntax_ error pointing to the right of the ]]** at the end of input. I have not done a sub-list before, so not familiar with that error.

Comment: If you copy/pasted @slibby 's code, remove the asterisks at the end of the line.

Comment: @recurvata, thank you. Almost there! Now before **except** towards the end, I have a highlighted area and the error _unexpected unindent_ .Apologies for the novice Qs; this is only my second script!

Comment: @WolverineTime please update the code in your original post to reflect what you currently have.

Comment: The posted code looks fine as far as indents. Check that all indents line up properly in your actual code. Sometimes it can make a difference if you mix tabs and spaces, even though both can be 4 spaces, for example.

Comment: @recurvata, thank you. My **Try** was not indented far enough to the right. I modified that, tabbed all the sections and lined up **except** with **try**. Newbie.

Comment: @ian, I have updated my code in the original Q. But now I see "**Converting Excel file to table**" four times, the >>> afterwards, and nothing else happens.

Comment: you may want to update your except block, because it should be  printing errors.  In the `Transform` line, you just have `[0]`, not `ss[0]`, so I assuming there is a syntax error (you can't concatenate a textpath1 which is a string with [0] which is a list) or something of the sort..

Comment: @mr.adam , no idea how to print the errors. Just modified the list part though

Comment: Ok, I had to look it up, and I think you got no messages because it was a python error, not an arcpy error.  To improve the messages, I'd recommend taking the except block from this documentation: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000q000000  Scroll down to the section called traceback and take that except code.  You'll have to import the `traceback` and `sys` modules at the top of the script too, but this except block will be super helpful in any future scripts too.

Comment: @mr.adam, thanks! That will be useful for me in the future too.